# JSTL Expression for test if Not

Tags: java, regex, jsp, jstl, taglib

I am trying  to know whether certain text starts with an expression "**Service include**.." using JSTL condition. However, I see that this expression is incorrect and error some. Can you please identify what is wrong with this.

Below is part of JSP page.

```
<%--  
    Attributes: ruleView
    RuleViewDto ruleView
--%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:set var="ruleDesc" value="${rule.description}"/>

<c:if test="${!fn:startsWith(ruleDesc, 'Service include')}">        

    <td align="right"  class="imgButton"
        onclick="RuleSet.removeRule('${ruleView.stepId}', '${rule.code}');" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" 
        ><img src="../img/delete.gif" /></td>
</c:if>
```

What is wrong with Expression `${!fn:startsWith(ruleDesc, 'Service include')}` ? How how should it be ?

Comment: `startWith` is also working fine but it works only if the text is present in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Well I would expect you to write the el as ${not fn:startsWith(bla)}

Comment: @Braj, I want to know if ruleDesc starts with 'Service include'

Comment: @Gimby, I want to compare txt1 is present in txt2.

Comment: Okay, I guess it is my fault that I am not specific enough. I mean you use the word 'not'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is wrong with Expression `${!fn:startsWith(ruleDesc, 'Service include')}`

the expression itself looks good, one thing you didn't specify in the JSP is a taglib used for `fn` namespace. Add this `taglib` definition at beginning of the JSP page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

**WRONG#1:** `<c:if not test="${ some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

JasperException: **equal** symbol expected

**WRONG#2:** `<c:if Not test="${ some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

JasperException: java.lang.Class**NotFound**Exception:

**WRONG#3:** `<c:if test="${Not some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

ELException: Failed to parse the expression **+**
JasperException: contains invalid expression(s):

**WRONG#4:** `<c:if test=not"${ some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

JasperException: **quote** symbol expected

**WRONG#5:** `<c:if test=Not"${ some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

JasperException: java.lang.Class**NotFound**Exception:

**WRONG#6:** `<c:if test="${ ! some_bool }">MSG<c:if/>`

JasperException: The end tag "</c:forEach" is **unbalanced**

---

**CORRECT#1:** `<c:if test="${not some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

**CORRECT#2:** `<c:if test="${ !  some_bool }">MSG</c:if>`

Answer (score 2):

> whether certain text doesn't `contain` expression "Service include.."

You can use `indexOf` that return -1 if doesn't contain

```
${fn:indexOf(ruleDesc, 'Service include')==-1}
```

---

You can try ignore case as well

```
${fn:indexOf(ruleDesc.toLowerCase(), 'service include')==-1}
```

---

#### EDIT

please test it again at your end with below sample code:

```
<c:set var="ruleDesc" value="abc Service include abc" />
Not starts with: ${!fn:startsWith(ruleDesc, 'Service include')}
```

Comment: +1 for reply. Unfortunately, I want to know if text starts with 'Service include' :)

Comment: Can you please tell what is wrong with my expression?

Comment: I have tested for `startsWith()` and working fine at my end as I already mentioned that's why I shared another approach.